# Is there a MIDI music notation program (e.g. Finale) that automatically detects rhythm?

Tags: notation, software, rhythm, midi

I want to notate some piano songs that I have written. My problem is that I can't find a program that will record the pitch *and* the rhythm of the note. In every program that I've seen, you have to manually enter the duration of the note. I have a MIDI keyboard and a MIDI-USB cable. I have computers that run Windows (XP, 7), Linux (Ubuntu), and Mac (PowerPC 10.4). I have tried Anvil Studio, Finale Notepad, and Musescore so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in any notation program I'm familiar with.  In Finale (my choice), you use the HyperScribe function, outlined here:

http://www.finalemusic.com/usermanuals/finale2012win/content/finale/ID_MAINTOOL_HYPERSCRIBE.htm

I'm fairly certain Finale Notepad has this function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one: http://notionmusic.com/

Using it on the iPad and Mac, works for me and is cheaper than most others. No need to manually modify pitch and note length.

You may want to watch this:

Shows how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, take a look at http://rosegardenmusic.com/

It opens to a MIDI view initially, where you can record from your MIDI keyboard. The software quantizes the note durations into the program's internal representation, and with a click of a button you can switch to the score view to see the resulting sheet music.

There's also a Windows port of Rosegarden, but I believe it depends on KDE, and I don't know if they got the sound playback working yet.

Disclaimer: I'm listed as one of the Rosegarden developers, courtesy of two patches I contributed a few years ago.